# conditions on the matrix s.t. the matrix is not known explicitly although the stationary distribution is known.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

We know that if the transition probability matrix of a Markov chain is doubly stochastic (column sum also 1) then the stationary distribution is known ($\frac{1}{\text{no. of states}}$) although the exact matrix is not known.

I am interested in knowing similar conditions on the matrix s.t. the matrix is not known explicitly although the stationary distribution is known.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be a $n\times n$ (row-)stochastic matrix such that $\pi P = \pi$ where $\pi_i=\frac1n$, $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$. Then for each column $j$, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i P_{ij} = \pi_j, $$ hence $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1n P_{ij} = \frac1n, $$ and multiplying by $n$ we see that the columns sum to $1$. So the stationary distribution is uniform if and only if $P$ is doubly stochastic.

Comment: shouldn't it be $\pi P = \pi$?

Comment: @Leaderboard281923 Indeed, I fixed the typo.

Comment: Okay. This might be a stupid question but why the summation is equal to $\pi_{j}$? It should be i instead of j?

Comment: Am I right about this?

Comment: @Leaderboard281923 the summation is doing the dot product between $\pi$ and the $j$th column of $P$ and therefor the $j$th value in $\pi$.